# ESP-IDF Project Structure Issue: 'Undefined Reference to Function' Error

Tags: cmake, esp32, arduino-esp32

I've started a project based on the ESP-IDF example 'blink' and am trying to reorganize it into a more structured format. My goal is to have a project structure like this:

```
BLINK/
├── components/
│   ├── arduino/
│   ├── lib1/
│   │   ├── include/
│   │   │   └── foo.h
│   │   ├── src/
│   │   │   └── foo.c
│   │   └── CMakeLists.txt
│   └── ...
├── main/
│   └── main.c
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── sdkconfig
└── README.md
```

I modified `main.c` in the `main` folder as follows:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include "sdkconfig.h"
#include "../components/lib1/include/foo.h"

void app_main() {
    printfoo(); 
    while (1) {      
    }
}
```

Here are the contents of the files in my `lib1` component:

- `foo.h`:

  ```c
  #include <stdio.h>
  void printfoo();
  ```
- `foo.c`:

  ```c
  #include "foo.h"

  void printfoo() {
      printf("Hello from Foo\r\n");
  }
  ```
- `CMakeLists.txt` in `BLINK/components/lib1/`:

  ```
  set(COMPONENT_SRCS "foo.c")
  set(COMPONENT_ADD_INCLUDEDIRS "." "include")
  register_component()
  ```

When I compile the project, I get the following error:

```
main.c:6: undefined reference to `printfoo'
```

I know that this error output means that linker couldn't find definition of the function *printfoo* which located in foo.c

Any suggestions on what might be causing this error and how to resolve it?

***update***: I am using ESP-IDF  version v3.3.6.

I have followed the ESP32 guide on [Component CMakeLists Files](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/api-guides/build-system.html?highlight=cmakelists#component-cmakelists-files) but am still encountering this issue.

Answer (score 0):

**General**
I think the problem is that you set you're source to `foo.c`, but the that file is at `src/foo.c`. Thus, the source file isn't added and as a consequence, the function isn't implemented.

**ESP-IDF v3.3.6**
In ESP-IDF v3.3.6, the following CMakeLists.txt should work:

```
set(COMPONENT_SRCS "src/foo.c")
set(COMPONENT_ADD_INCLUDEDIRS "include")
register_component()
```

[More information/documentatio v3.3.6](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/v3.3.6/api-guides/build-system-cmake.html#minimal-component-cmakelists)

**ESP-IDF v5.x**
In version v5.x, `SRCS` and `INCLUDE_DIRS` are commonly used instead of `COMPONENT_SRCS` and `COMPONENT_ADD_INCLUDEDIRS` respectively.
In ESP-IDF v5.x, the following CMakeLists.txt should work:

```
idf_component_register(SRCS "src/foo.c"
                       INCLUDE_DIRS "include")
```

[More information/documentatio v5.x](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/api-guides/build-system.html#minimal-component-cmakelists)

**General**
Then, in main, you should be able to include `foo.h` in the following way:

```c
#include "foo.h"
```

Comment: thanks for your comment, I am using version v3.3.6 and I have no choice to use other versions.

Comment: I updated the answer for ESP-IDF v3.3.6, does this work?

Comment: it's very strange , now i am getting the following error : main.c:3:17: fatal error: foo.h: No such file or directory

if i included foo.h like this : #include "../components/lib1/include/foo.h", i get the first error 
undefined reference to `printfoo'

Answer (score 0):

***ESP-IDF v3.3.6***

I solved this issue, by add a file named `component.mk` to the project with the following content:

```
COMPONENT_ADD_INCLUDEDIRS := .
```

Beside this addition, i modifed the project structure as shown below:

```
BLINK/
├── components/
│   ├── arduino/
│   ├── lib1/
│   │   ├── foo.h
│   │   ├── foo.c
│   │   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   │   └── component.mk
│   └── ...
├── main/
│   └── main.c
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── sdkconfig
└── README.md
```

In the `lib1` component of the project, the final contents of the files should be as follows:

- `foo.h`:

  ```c
  #include <stdio.h>
  void printfoo();
  ```
- `foo.c`:

  ```c
  #include "foo.h"

  void printfoo() {
      printf("Hello from Foo\r\n");
  }
  ```
- `CMakeLists.txt` in `BLINK/components/lib1/`:

  ```
    set(COMPONENT_SRCS "foo.c")
    set(COMPONENT_ADD_INCLUDEDIRS "." )
    register_component()
  ```
- `component.mk` in `BLINK/components/lib1/`:

  ```
  COMPONENT_ADD_INCLUDEDIRS := .
  ```

Finally, main application code (`app_main`) in `BLINK/main/main.c` should include the necessary headers and invoke `printfoo()` as follows:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include "sdkconfig.h"
#include "foo.h"

void app_main() {
    printfoo(); 
    while (1) {      
    }
}
```